# Выравнивание блоков поровну

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Есть 10 блоков, в каждом из них есть картинка. Как выровнять их внутри его родителя так, что бы блоки делились поровну. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="tour-list-content">
                    <div class="first-list-image">
                        <div class="image img1">
                            <div class="image-content">
                                <span>Russian</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Блоки должны делиться поровну в определнном кол-ве на строку? Или они должны занимать одинаковое пространство? Напишите подробнее, чтобы решить вашу задачу.

Comment: Да, блоки делятся поровну, и занимают одинаковое пространство

Answer (score -1):

```
Решил я вот таким способом, но возможно есть другой, чему я буду рад



    .first-screen .container .tour-list .image{
     width: 100px;
     height: 70px;
     flex-basis: 110px;
    }
    .first-screen .container .tour-list .tour-list-content .first-list-image{
     padding: 0 40px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .first-screen .container .tour-list .tour-list-content .second-list-image{
     margin-top: 55px;
     padding: 0 40px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
    }
    <div class="tour-list">
        <div class="paragraph-content">
            <span>places you must visit in your life</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tour-list-content">
            <div class="first-list-image">
                <div class="image img1">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>Russian</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image img2">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>Ukraine</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image img3">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>New-York</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image img4">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>China</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image img5">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>Kazakhstan</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second-list-image">
                <div class="image img6">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>Dagestan</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image img7">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>Japan</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image img8">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>USA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image img9">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>Canada</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image img10">
                    <div class="image-content">
                        <span>Belarus</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line-bottom">

        </div>
    </div>
```